# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have this file that checks if the user is authenticated, if yes it sends me to the profile else it goes to the login page but when the user is not authenticated I receive that error up above:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const PrivateRoute2 = ({ children }) =>{

const [isloggedin, setLoggedin] = useState(false)
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

const isUserAuth = async() =>{
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/isUSerAuth',{
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token") },   
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data.auth)
      if(data.auth === true){
        setLoggedin(true)
      }else{
        setLoggedin(false)
      }
      console.log(isloggedin)
      setIsLoading(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }

    }
    useEffect(()=>{
         isUserAuth();
    }, [])

    return (
    isLoading ? <p>Loading....</p> : isloggedin ? children : <Navigate to ="/login" />
     );


     }

    export default PrivateRoute2
```

And in App.js I nested the profile inside the privateroute2 and as I said I get that error in the title:

```
function App () {
return (
  <div className="App">
    
    
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
      <Route path='/login' element={
           <PrivateRoute2>
           <Profile />
         </PrivateRoute2>
      } />
      <Route path='/profile' element={
           <PrivateRoutes>
           <Profile />
         </PrivateRoutes>
      } />
      <Route path="/404" element={<Err404 />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
        );
      }



      export default App;
```

and it also says in the error:
"but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the condition inside PrivateRoute2.js like this:

```
return (
    isLoading ? <p>Loading....</p> : isloggedin ? <Navigate to ="/profile" 
/> : children
 );
```

and then I wrapped the login.js as a child:

```
<Route path='/login' element={
          <PrivateRoute2>
           <Login />
         </PrivateRoute2>
      } />
```

Comment: Is the issue resolved now ?

Comment: yes bro it is :)